# Jquery 1.9, JS - function is not defined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is really puzzling me. I have function defined in **main.js** file, which is loaded in the header, and then latter on I am calling that function at the end of HTML code. In Chrome I am getting error **Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_image is not defined**, but in Firefox it is working normally (same error is appearing in Opera). What is going on?

Function:

```
function delete_image(button, data = false){
    button.on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    url = $(this).attr('href');

    if( data == 'tmp' )
    {
        data = 'id=' + $this.data('id');
    }
    else if ( data == true )
    {
        data = forma.serialize();
    }

    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Image Delete',
        'message'   : 'Do you want to delete this image?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    $.post(url, data,  function(){
                        $this.parent().slideUp('slow');
                    });
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
};
```

Calling the function (after HTML part of the code):

```
<script>
    var link = $('a[role=delete]');
    delete_image(link);
</script>
```

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you're using `data` to represent a few different types. you should try to use it as only a single type. Additionally, it's not a great variable name, and you're losing access to it inside of your `confirm` function. Try to come up with a name that better represents what you're using that variable for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't pass a default argument value in standard javascript today, this is invalid in Chrome :

```
function delete_image(button, data = false){
```

What you should do is

```
function delete_image(button, data){
    if (data == undefined) data=false;
```

The MDN [precises in what browsers you can use this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters) (answer : only Firefox).

This should be available with Harmony. Here's [some detail about ES6's plan](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aparameter_default_values).

Comment: @Sasha they're testing a lot of things before they get official in ES, and sometimes they never get mainstream. Another example : [Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Comment: Cool :). Thank you for helping me and giving me extra explanation :)